# El Front End no Responde

Tags: .net, blazor

Estoy haciendo una api con .net 8 de backend y blazord como front, y estoy teniendo problemas con el frontend.

A la hora de querer logearme o registrarme pareciera como que no me consume la api por que a la hora de logearme o registrarme no me sale ninguna advertencia de verificaciones o los  popup diciendo que fue exitoso.

Les comparto todo el código que tengo hasta ahora en mi repositorio,  https://github.com/LrFontana/SistemaDeGestionEmpleados, y les dejo las fotos de las respuesta del back que es 200 y lo que me devuelve el front.

Cualquier ayuda se los agradecería, saludos.

[image: introducir la descripción de la imagen aquí]

[introducir la descripción de la imagen aquí](https://i.stack.imgur.com/3L2Kj.jpg)

[image: introducir la descripción de la imagen aquí]

[image: introducir la descripción de la imagen aquí]

Comment: Un [repro] del código en cuestión debe estar _en la pregunta misma_. Recuerda que los enlaces externos pueden caer, por lo que si llega a pasar, tu pregunta carecerá de mayor contexto. Lee [ask] y haz el [tour] para conocer el funcionamiento del sitio.

Comment: Es que no se está haciendo ninguna llamada a la api. ¿No tendrías que poner en el formulario una propiedad `OnValidSubmit` para que se ejecute?